# Write a regexp parsing URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex which will do the following

If I have url like

```
example.com?mask=33&filter=23423&mode=12
```

It will match substring filter=23423

I need also to consider that the url can be

```
example.com?filter=23423
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might do: `/filter=(\d+)/`

Comment: Once matched, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Thanks. I want to be able to change it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just not consider [\?&] in your regexp and put /filter=[0-9]*/  if you sure that there will not be any params like other_filter=987 in your url.
If you may have such use substr on the resulted regexp like so

```
url.match(/[\?&]filter=[0-9]*/)[0].substr(1)
```